# Algorithm to determine if $L_1$ is a subset of $L_2$ in Automata Theory

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language

I need to create a pseudo Algorithm to determine if $L_1$ is a subset of $L_2$ where both are regular languages with a given DFA.

I thought about creating the intersection automaton of $L_1$ and $L_2$ and see if the intersection is equal to $L_1$ that way we'll know it's a subset of $L_2$.

But I'm not sure how to prove that the intersection is equal to $L_1$ and also am I even allowed to do intersection/union on two automatons if I don't know whether or not they have the same alphabet?

Comment: Yes: there are algorthmic procedures to compute DFAs that accept the intersection and the union of two regular languages given some DFA for them, and there is an algorithmic procedure to decide if two DFAs accept the same language (namely, check if their minimal DFAs are isomorphic graphs).

Comment: That being said, an alphabet for the language is an inherent piece of information in any descritpion of a regular language (DFA included), therefore I would argue that if you don't know the alphabets for $L_1$ and $L_2$, then you can't say anything about them.

Comment: Well, You don't know in advance whether they're equal but the algorithm get the DFA's so it also gets the alphabet.

Comment: Oh, I see now. You can make them both DFAs over $\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2$ by adding to DFA n°$1$ transtions from each state to a dead state for every $x\in \Sigma_2\setminus\Sigma_1$ and to DFA n°$2$ transtions from each state to a dead state for every $x\in \Sigma_1\setminus\Sigma_2$.

Comment: Can I use the intersection between L1 and the complement of L2 that and say that in the intersection automaton there should be no paths to an accepting state because the intersection should be an empty set if L1 is a subset of L2 ?

Comment: It's a valid idea, possibly the best one.

Answer (score 2):

You’ve already figured out the main part of the problem in the comments. If the two DFAs have the same alphabet, then we can check whether the languages are the same by constructing DFAs which recognise $L_1 \cap L_2^c$ and $L_1^c \cap L_2$ and testing whether either DFA recognises at least 1 string.

If the two don’t have the same alphabet, we can extend the DFAs to operate on the combined accident by adding a new failure state. More precisely, let $\Sigma_i$ be the alphabet for the DFA recognising $L_i$ for $i = 1, 2$. We extend the DFA for $L_1$ by adding a single failure state $f$. $f$ will always transition to itself and is not an accepting state, and any state from the original DFA should transition to $f$ upon seeing any character in $\Sigma_2 \setminus \Sigma_1$. This gives us a new DFA recognising the same language but with the expanded alphabet $\Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2$. Do the same for the other DFA.

All in all, this gives us a polynomial time algorithm for checking whether two DFAs recognise the same language. An alternative would be computing the minimal DFA for each language and comparing them, which is also a polynomial time algorithm but would probably be somewhat more complicated.

Comment: For the proof method in my previous comment I need to rely on the fact that that L1⊆L2 ⇔ L1∩Lc2^c=∅ is true. I'm not sure about the right to left, is its always true?

Comment: Yes. Suppose the right hand side is true, and suppose $x \in L_1$. Either $x \in L_2$, in which case we’re good, or $x \notin L_2$, in which case we have a contradiction.